# How to get url .pdf + text from <td> ... class + onclick ...<td>

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, onclick, output

Can someone give me a tip how to find the way?
I need to get link of pdf file + the text("Instructions (DE)") from this tag:

```
<td class="col-download-data" onclick="openPdf('https://www.roco.cc/static/version1662032330/frontend/Casisoft/Roco/en_GB/doc/AN/1/DE/62200-BA_7937.pdf');">Instructions (DE)</td>
```

No, I am getting this output:
openPdf('https://www.roco.cc/static/version1662032330/frontend/Casisoft/Roco/en_GB/doc/ET/1/DE/69255_11395.pdf');

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

productlinks = []

for x in range(1, 2):
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={x}&verfuegbarkeit_status=41%2C42%2C43%2C45%2C44')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item product product-item')

    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', class_='product-item-link', href=True):
            productlinks.append(link['href'])

for url in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    for tag in content.find_all('a'):
        on_click = tag.get('onclick')
        if on_click:
            print(on_click)
```

Comment: Just extract the text between the single quotes from `on_click` and you have your PDF URL.

Comment: And anybody have a hint for how extract the text: ("Instructions (DE)") ?

Comment: Change `productlinks.append(link['href'])` to `productlinks.append((link['href'], link.text))`. This will make `productlinks` a list of 2-element tuples, the `0` element being the href and the `1` element the `<td>`'s text. If you do this, change your `for` loop `for url in productlinks:` to `for url, text in productlinks:` because you're unpacking tuples now instead of just regular list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
for url in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    for tag in content.find_all('a'):
        on_click = tag.get('onclick')
        if on_click:
            pdf = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", on_click)
            print(pdf)
```